# How the constructor allocates memory in C #

Tags: c#

```
class Tree<T>
    {
        
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public List<Tree<T>> Children { get; private set; }

        public Tree(T value, params Tree<T>[] children)
        {
            Value = value;
            Children = new List<Tree<T>>();
            foreach (Tree<T> child in children)
            {
                Children.Add(child);
            }
        }

class Programing
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tree<int> tree =
                new Tree<int>(7,
                    new Tree<int>(12,
                        new Tree<int>(9),
                        new Tree<int>(31),
                        new Tree<int>(16)));
            tree.Print();
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain how this nested constructor works in memory. I am not very clear about how memory allocation and place of the nested constructor is done?

Comment: from the inside to the outside. In order to construct the most outside object, you surely need a fully constructed nested one, which itself needs its own subtree and so on, until you finally can construct a tree that does not need any subtree. Seems clear that you construct those first

Comment: Allocates on the heap for each object you create (which includes the list for each tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree is a class, so all instances are allocated on the Heap, and eventually garbage collected and released.

`Tree<T>` and `Tree<int>` are different types, with different `T Value` properties. If `T` was a class, then the property would be a pointer to another location on the Heap. But since you are using a value type; `Tree<int>`, the `Value` property will just be an `int` stored directly within the memory allocated to the `Tree<int>` instance.

Constructors, like other method calls, can only be executed after all of their argument expressions have been evaluated, from left to right. The `params` argument is syntactic sugar, the compiler will insert the additional array creation before calling the function.

Ignoring that the integer values are also pushed onto a stack first, the execution order would be;

```cs
var t1 = new Tree<int>(9);
var t2 = new Tree<int>(31);
var t3 = new Tree<int>(16);
var t4 = new Tree<int>[] {t1, t2, t3};
var t5 = new Tree<int>(12, t4);
var t6 = new Tree<int>[] {t5};
Tree<int> tree = new Tree<int>(7, t6);
```

However, each instance of `Tree<int>`, and each `List<Tree<int>>` created in the constructor, could be allocated anywhere in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It would first evaluate the innermost tree. Each tree is passed as an argument to it's parent and like with any method call, arguments are evaluated first before being passed down. The resultant order would be equivalent to,

```
var a = new Tree<int>(9),
var b = new Tree<int>(31),
var c = new Tree<int>(16);
var d = new Tree<int>(12, a, b, c);
Tree<int> tree = new Tree<int>(7, d);
```

Allocations would follow the typical object allocation pattern without any special considerations.